# QUERY MARIA DB PARA FILTAR APENAS TIMESTAMP ATUAL

Tags: banco-de-dados, select

A query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    hosts.name as "Unidade de Negócio",
    CASE
        WHEN services.acknowledged = 1
            THEN acknowledgements.comment_data
        ELSE 0
    END AS "Análise",
    hosts.last_state_change*1000 as "Duração",
    acknowledgements.entry_time
FROM
    hosts
    INNER JOIN services ON services.host_id=hosts.host_id
    LEFT  JOIN acknowledgements ON acknowledgements.host_id = hosts.host_id
WHERE
    hosts.enabled = 1
    AND hosts.name LIKE 'pa-%'
    AND services.description = 'Status FG.'
    AND hosts.output not LIKE '%ok%'
    AND services.state = 2
    AND services.scheduled_downtime_depth =0
    ORDER BY acknowledgements.entry_time DESC
```

O problema:

Está repetindo as 3 primeiras colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fez `join` com `services` e nessa tabela parece existir 3 registros distintos para esse mesmo `host`. Qual era o resultado esperado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o resultado esperado é trazer todos os nomes dos hosts com o ultimo comentário atualizado e a duração que ele está no monitoramento, mas cada vez que atualizamos o comentário ele faz um insert para ficar no log e isso faz com que o dado se repita, a unica coisa que não repete é o entry time, porém mesmo quando uso um group by nos campos e depois um order by no entry time, apenas é ordenado o entry time e host, mas o comentário que é o que preciso não, ou seja, não funciona com apenas group by.  Estou utilizando a versão 5.5 do mariadb.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um `GROUP BY` pelas três primeiras colunas e um `MAX` para pegar o maior `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.name as "Unidade de Negócio",
                CASE
                    WHEN s.acknowledged = 1
                        THEN a.comment_data
                    ELSE 0
                END AS "Análise",
                h.last_state_change * 1000 as "Duração",
                MAX(a.entry_time) AS a.entry_time
  FROM hosts h
 INNER JOIN services s ON s.host_id=h.host_id
  LEFT JOIN acknowledgements a ON a.host_id = h.host_id
 WHERE h.enabled = 1
   AND h.name LIKE 'pa-%'
   AND s.description = 'Status FG.'
   AND h.output not LIKE '%ok%'
   AND s.state = 2
   AND s.scheduled_downtime_depth =0
 GROUP BY h.name, s.acknowledged, h.last_state_change
 ORDER BY a.entry_time DESC
```